# How to see Qt Source code while coding by Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

How to see Qt Source code while coding by Qt Creator ?
when I Debug my program and hit a break point, and when I press F11 over a Qt function , Debugger steps into source code of that function, it is very interesting stuff :D
now, I will see the source code of Qt functions in Qt creator while coding , not at Debug time :D

Comment: I don't think you can browse the Qt .cpp files unless they are part of a creator project (which is not what you want). Or in debugging mode of course, where the information is pulled from the executable. Browsing declarations, i.e. header files, works though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a debug build of Qt, and you have to build it yourself. Building Qt is easy: see the [Installation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/installation.html) part of the documentation.

#### Adding the debug version to Qt Creator

The following instructions are for Qt Creator 2.0.0. If you're using a different version, adapt as needed. First, you need to add your debug build to the list of available Qt Versions.

1. Select the **Tools** > **Options** menu;
2. Pick the **Qt4** page;
3. Click the **+** button;
4. Click the **Browse** button and select the qmake binary that is inside the `bin` directory of your custom-built Qt;
5. Click **Rebuild** to build the debugging helpers. This is important!
6. Click **OK**.

Now, configure the project to use your debug build during compilation.

1. Back in the Qt Creator main window, select the **Projects** view;
2. Pick the tab corresponding to your project;
3. Select **Build Settings**;
4. On **General**, change the **Qt Version** to the version you added on the previous part.

*Rebuild your project from scratch* with the new settings. You should now be able to debug into Qt code.

Comment: I have built Qt source code. Now please tell me what do I have to do ?

Comment: Doesn't work for Qt 3.3, if you can update the answer would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help but I don't use Qt 3.

Answer (score 1):

F2 is "follow symbol under cursor". That should get you to the right place, independently of whether the code was provided by some included header file or not.

Your own projects will most likely not include the Qt source files though, so you can not jump into them directly (they are not referenced from the project, so they are not there for creator). So during editing you will not be able to just jump straight into the Qt source code. Debugging will of course work (see previous answer, buit rebuilding your own Qt shouldn't actually be necessary).

You can open the projects.pro file found in the Qt sources as an additional project in creator. Then you can at least use the locator (Ctrl-K) to look up methods, etc.

Hope this helps...